# How to make Automator open only one instance of the Terminal Application?

Tags: terminal, automator

I have created an Automator App which would open a Terminal window and connect to a server.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "ssh_connect"
    activate
end tell
```

Note: the `ssh_connect` is a shortcut created by me.

However, every time I clicked on the App icon, it creates a new Terminal window and what I want is just to bring the existed window back to front if already created.

What should I do to make this happen?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the window and/or tab that `do script` runs in?

Comment: Wouldn't be better in this case to write shell scripts or aliases to continure in the current window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, every time I clicked on the App icon, it creates a new Terminal window and what I want is just to bring the existed window back to front if already created.
>
> What should I do to make this happen?

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** as a *script*, and saved as an **AppleScript** *application*, under **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set shellCMD to "ssh_connect"

tell application "Terminal"
    
    activate
    
    if exists (tabs of windows whose history contains shellCMD) then
        set winID to ¬
            the id of the first window ¬
                whose history of tab 1 contains shellCMD
        set index of window id winID to 1
        set frontmost of window id winID to true
    else
        if (exists window 1) and ¬
            (busy of tab 1 of window 1 is false) then
            do script shellCMD in window 1
        else
            do script shellCMD
        end if
    end if
    
end tell
```

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and is meant to show a way of coding based on given conditions.

Since this is being run as a standalone **AppleScript** *application*, as currently coded, what it will do is:

- If **Terminal** is not running, it opens **Terminal** and runs the `do script` *command* in the first window.
- If **Terminal** is running and a *window* exists with the *value* of `shellCMD` in its *history*, it brings that window frontmost, even if it's minimized.
- If **Terminal** is running and **no** *window* exists, then a new *window* is created and runs the `do script` *command*.
- If **Terminal** is running and **no** *window* exists with the *value* of `shellCMD` in its *history* and `window 1` exists and is not currently processing a *command*, then the `do script` *command* is processed in `window 1`.

You can adjust the *example* **AppleScript** *code* to suit your needs.

This should work for versions of **macOS** from **macOS High Sierra** and later.

For versions of **macOS** prior to **macOS High Sierra** the *example* **AppleScript** *code* will need to be modified due to how **Terminal** handles multiple *tabs* in a *window*.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer. So I could change `shellCMD` to any string that I want, right?

Comment: @AGamePlayer, RE: "So I could change `shellCMD` to any string that I want, right?" --  Yes, as long as it's a properly formed _command_ I don't foresee an issue.

Comment: Oh, I found an issue. If I have more than one Terminal window opened, then I clicked the Automator-created App and then close the newly created window. It won't do the script again but just bringing another window to upfront.

Comment: It seems that the `if exists (tabs of windows whose history contains shellCMD) then` statement is not working properly. I'm on `big sur 11.4 (20F71)`

Comment: @AGamePlayer, RE: "Automator-created App" --  Does it have to be an **Automator** _application_, why not just save the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_, as is, as an **AppleScript** _application_ from **Script Editor**? If you want me to troubleshoot an **Automator** _application_, then you'll need to provide all the relevant details of the **Automator** _workflow_.  --  I'll test the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ as is in **macOS Big Sur** as an **AppleScript** _application_ and see that it functions as described in my answer.

Comment: @AGamePlayer, Okay, I've tested this under **macOS Big Sur** based on what's stated in the answer and it performs as stated in the answer. If it's not doing something that you want, then you'll need to further clarify what you need beyond what you've stated in your original question.

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience. I have found the reason. I need to restart `Terminal` app. I have a lot of terminal windows opened and after closing all of them, the problem is gone.

Comment: And for the Automator app, it's because I need an icon and put that icon in the dock so that I can run this on the fly.

Comment: @AGamePlayer,  RE: "And for the Automator app, it's because I need an icon and put that icon in the dock so that I can run this on the fly." --  You can do the same thing with an **AppleScript** _application_ and it is less resource intensive and runs faster than doing it as an **Automator** _application_.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is there any tutorial or stackexchange questions recommended for me to get started?

Comment: @AGamePlayer, A tutorial for what? Just copy and paste the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ into **Script Editor** and save it as an _application_. Then you can give it a custom icon thru the icon in the upper left corner on it's **Info Sheet**.   Select the _application_ and press: **⌘I**. Copy the source image in **Preview** and then paste it in to the **Info Sheet** after selecting the icon in the upper left corner.